ApexCharts: y-axis label color not working (x-axis works fine)
I'm working with ApexCharts  and I'm facing an issue where the y-axis label color isn't being applied. The x-axis color is working correctly, though.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
// Setting x-axis labels
    XAxis xAxis = XAxisBuilder.get()
        .withCategories(continuous.size() > oneTime.size() ? continuousKeys : oneTimeKeys)
        .withTooltip(TooltipBuilder.get().withEnabled(false).build())
        .withLabels(com.github.appreciated.apexcharts.config.xaxis.builder.LabelsBuilder.get()
            .withStyle(StyleBuilder.get()
                .withColors(IntStream.range(0, xSize).mapToObj(x -> "#FFFFFF").collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .build())
            .build())
        .build();
    chart.setXaxis(xAxis);

    // Setting y-axis labels
    YAxis yAxis = YAxisBuilder.get()

        .withLabels(LabelsBuilder.get()
            .withFormatter(
                "function(val) { if (val >= 1000000) { return (val / 1000000).toFixed(1) + 'M'; } else { return val / 1000 + 'K'; } }")
            .withStyle(com.github.appreciated.apexcharts.config.yaxis.labels.builder.StyleBuilder.get()
                .withColor("#FFFFFF").build())
            .build())
        .withTooltip(TooltipBuilder.get().withEnabled(false).build())
        .build();
    chart.setYaxis(new YAxis[] { yAxis });

In this code, I'm setting the color for the y-axis labels to white (#FFFFFF), but they are not changing color. I expect them to be white, but they remain the default color.


After encountering an issue with ApexCharts where the y-axis label font color wasn't being applied, I found an alternative solution. By setting the theme to dark mode, which made all fonts white, and adjusting the background of the chart to match my page, I achieved the desired result.
